# c++ 11 recursive class template to complex error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion

Why do I get an "error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex" error when change the #if 0 to #if 1?  The erroring version is simpler and I'd rather use something like it.

I'm trying to write a hash function that eliminates looping for compile time constant lengths.  The real hash function is more complex, this is just a simple example.

```
typedef unsigned __int8 U1;
typedef unsigned __int16 U2;
typedef unsigned __int32 U4;
#define  AS1(a_)        (*(U1*)(a_))
#define  AS2(a_)        (*(U2*)(a_))
#define  AS3(a_)        ((U4(((U1*)(a_))[2])<<16) | AS2(a_))
#define  AS4(a_)        (*(U4*)(a_))

#if 0
template<U4 CB> U4 Hash(const char* sz, int n = 0) {
    if (CB >= 4) return Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4, n ^ AS4(sz));
    if (CB == 3) return n ^ AS3(sz);
    if (CB == 2) return n ^ AS2(sz);
    if (CB == 1) return n ^ AS1(sz);
}
#else
template<U4 CB> U4 Hash(const char* sz) {
    return Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4, Hash<4>(sz));
}
template<U4 CB> U4 Hash(const char* sz, int n) {
    return Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4, Hash<4>(sz, n));
}
template<> U4 Hash<1>(const char* sz, int n)        { return n ^ AS1(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<2>(const char* sz, int n)        { return n ^ AS2(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<3>(const char* sz, int n)        { return n ^ AS3(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<4>(const char* sz, int n)        { return n ^ AS4(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<1>(const char* sz)           { return AS1(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<2>(const char* sz)           { return AS2(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<3>(const char* sz)           { return AS3(sz); }
template<> U4 Hash<4>(const char* sz)           { return AS4(sz); }
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* sz = "123456789";
    int n = Hash<9>(sz);
    n += Hash<3>(sz);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this function is infinitely recursive at compile time:

```
template<U4 CB> U4 Hash(const char* sz, int n = 0) {
    if (CB >= 4) return Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4, n ^ AS4(sz));
    if (CB == 3) return n ^ AS3(sz);
    if (CB == 2) return n ^ AS2(sz);
    if (CB == 1) return n ^ AS1(sz);
}
```

Sure, you have `if` statements, so that if you call `Hash<3>` you don't really expect it to want to instantiate `Hash<-1>`... but in templates, the entire body of the function has to be instantiated. The branches only get pruned later. So regardless of the value of `CB`, any instantiation of `Hash` will keep instantiating more and more values of `CB` (e.g. `Hash<9>` requires `Hash<5>` requires `Hash<1>` requires `Hash<-3>` requires `Hash<-7>` ... ) until it hits the compiler template recursion limit or the compiler just runs out of memory

On the other hand, if you explicitly specialize all the cases:

```
template<U4 CB> U4 Hash(const char* sz, int n = 0) {
    return Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4, n ^ AS4(sz));
}

template <> U4 Hash<3>(const char* sz, int n = 0) {
    return n ^ AS3(sz);
}

// etc.
```

Then the instantiation of, say, `Hash<9>` will lead to the instantiation of `Hash<5>`, then `Hash<1>` is just an explicit specialization and the process stops there.

That's why when it comes to template metaprogramming, you should think of specializations as your branches and your base recursive case. Don't think of actual run-time brunches.

Comment: Is there any way to simplify it so I don't need one that takes n and one that does not?

Comment: @johnnycrash You could rewrite to so that `Hash<CB>(sz)` is just `return AS4(sz) ^ Hash<CB - 4>(sz + 4);` But it might be better to keep it tail-recursive, you'd have to check what your compiler does to it.